# Use a text document to define a file path based on a prefix

Tags: c#

So I am trying to save file paths in text documents so that I can later edit them easily without changing any of the code.
How would I go about doing this? I was thinking using an array with a statement like this:

```
    foreach (string ExamplePath: in line)
```

Then when the program detects that line, it skips a space then reads the rest of the line and then makes that a string. I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: [File.WriteAlLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx) and [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: no, because I want to add a label in front of the path so that wouldn't work, thanks though

Comment: you can use web.config/app.config which is text file in xml format. I think it suitable for your purpose, and a lot easier to work with because built in .NET functions provided to read/write to it. how about that, any concern?